# Windows 7 Wireless suddenly stopped working

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Was using the internet on,wireless last night and it worked fine. This morning I tried turning it on and I got the error triangle at the bottom of the screen. I have tried resetting the router. I also tried allowing access to all internet traffic by disabling my firewall. I am using macafee. My mobile phone is working off the wireless. What do you think is wrong.i am also scanning for viruses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to connect to your router and select **wireless settings | wireless connection setup wizard** and try to run it and see if a wireless connection appears.

If not, can you tell the model of your wireless router? Check for firmware upgrades.